# Python range() builtin function, erm... malfunctioning with Django

Tags: python, django, date-range, built-in

What, if anything, is wrong with this line of python code:

```
daterange = [begin + timedelta(n) for n in range((end - begin).days)]
```

Where `begin` and `end` are `datetime.date` objects with valid values.

I'm using this in a Django view to process some data, but everytime the view this is in gets called I get the following error with the aforementioned line highlighted:

```
UnboundLocalError at /url/of/error/creating/view/here/
local variable 'range' referenced before assignment
```

If I execute this line inside the interpreter it works fine, but somehow it doesn't fly inside a Django view. I don't understand why `range` is being interpreted as a variable name at all. Is there actually something wrong with this line, or is it something else in the code that's making Django complain?

Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Django. You create a local variable `range` in the same scope (by assigning one). For instance `range = None` in the very last line of a function makes Python consider an occurrence of `range` in the first line of the same function a reference to that local variable. Since it doesn't have a value assigned at that point, you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're saying as I don't have any explicit variables name range anywhere in that method, or for that matter in the entire file.

Comment: @chands: Well, you *must* have one somewhere, or it wouldn't consider it a local variable. Show the source (of the method only).

Comment: Ahh crud. You're right. I had a misspelled variable name later in the method. My fault!

Comment: this is a very confusing point for new programmers.  It is big gotcha that I have encountered alot.

Comment: why the word is not reserved as a statement?